# How to set Fullcalendar.io time zones

Tags: javascript, php, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have the following code to initialize my Fullcalendar.io calendar:

```
<script>
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        timezone: "local",
        eventSources: [{
            url: 'load_adminevents.php',
        }],
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'list' ],
    });

    calendar.render();            
</script>
```

I have a select box to change the time zone:

```
<select class="calendarSelect" id="setTimeZone">
    <option value="local">Your local time</option>
    <option value="America/Toronto">Toronto (EST)</option>
    <option value="America/Vancouver">Vancouver (PST)</option>
</select>

<script>
    $("#setTimeZone").change(function(e){
        calendar.setOption('timezone',this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value);
    });
</script>
```

After reading and re-reading the docs, I'm still confused about what I'm supposed to do to update the times shown in the calendar after the timezone option is changed.

It sounds like I am supposed to do this in the backend (ie, in load_adminevents.php) but how do I know what the time zone that's been set is? The events are not re-loaded when the timezone option is changed.

If changing the time zone is supposed to be handled within the Javascript, how does this work? Sorry if this is obvious but the docs are not clear on this point. Thank you!

Comment: "in the backend...but how do I know what the time zone that's been set is" ...you don't. What you do is provide events whose dates already have a timezone offset specified. That way, when you then specify a timezone, fullCalendar will already know how to alter the date to show in the relevant timezone, because it already knows the offset of that date relative to UTC. The simplest approach in any backend DB, if you want timezone support, is to store all dates in UTC, and output all dates in UTC, with an offset of zero specified in the output string.

Comment: Take a look at the timezone-switching demo which fullCalendar provides: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExYMOgR?&editable=true&editors=001. Use your browser's network tools and take note of the format of the dates in the JSON event data which arrives in the calendar. I agree the documentation could be clearer, I had to read it a few times as well, but the demo makes it easier to comprehend.

Comment: P.S., `this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value` can be shortened to `this.value` - in a `<select>`, the `value` property always takes on the value of the currently selected option. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate this more tomorrow!